# Android GridVIew Change number of columns depending on Orientation

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I want to display 6 images in the form of grid as follows.

in portrait orientation,2 coumns, 3 rows and
in landscare orientation 3 columns, 2 rows

By using Android GridView and by defining different grid layouts in layout-port and layout-land directories I was able to achieve this effect.

Later as per my activity requirement, I added one parameter in manifest.xml that is

```
android:configChanges = "mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|fontScale|screenSize"`
```

to stop my activity to recreate once screen orientation changes.

After adding this parameter, my grid view is not behaving in expected way. It sometimes shows 1 column, sometimes 2 columns, and sometimes 3 columns.

I am placing `gridView.setNumberOfColumns(2)` or `gridView.setNumberOfColumns(3)` methods in the get view method of my grid adapter depending on orientation of the device.

Please help me to achieve this effect without removing the `android:configChanges` parameter in Manifest.xml

Answer (score 44):

Use the powerful resource system.

In the xml layout, set the number of columns to a integer resource and then in `/values/integers.xml` set it to 2 for portrait and in `/values-land/integers.xml` set it to 3 for landscape

// well, if you do configChanges in manifest, you will have to change column count from java in onConfogurationChanged

Comment: Thanks man. Now it is `values-land` and only `values` for the portrait mode, anyway +1.

Comment: I think it should be `values-land` and `values-port` (instead of sheer `values`) for better compatibility with various devices.

Answer (score 12):

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    grid.setNumColumns(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ? 3 : 2);
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

you can set number of columns programatically using

```
float scalefactor = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * 100;
int number = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
int columns = (int) ((float) number / (float) scalefactor);
gridView.setNumColumns(columns);
```

Comment: getDefaultDisplay().getWidth() is now deprecated. Is there another way of getting it?

Answer (score 4):

My solution:

**values/dimens.xml:**

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="grip_view_entry_size">160dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="grip_view_spacing">10dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

**layout/gridview.xml**

```
<GridView android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/grip_view_spacing"
    android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/grip_view_spacing"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:scrollingCache="false"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:animationCache="false"/>
```

**in your fragment:**

```
private void refreshGridView() {

    int gridViewEntrySize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.grip_view_entry_size);
    int gridViewSpacing = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.grip_view_spacing);

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

    int numColumns = (display.getWidth() - gridViewSpacing) / (gridViewEntrySize + gridViewSpacing);

    gridView.setNumColumns(numColumns);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    refreshGridView();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    refreshGridView();
}
```

Comment: this worked and should be accepted as correct answer

Answer (score 2):

```
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            setContentView(R.layout.lay_vertical);
        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            setContentView(R.layout.lay_horizontal);
        }

    };
```

Then load the data in gridview again according to your need.

Put android:configChanges="orientation" for that activity node in the manifest.

Comment: You will get exception, because `setContentView` can be called only once.

Comment: I dont think so that setcontentview can be called only once,instead all the things in that particular layout will have to be reinitialized with the things inside it by findViewById and it will go smooth

Answer (score 1):

While you use android:configChanges = "orientation" in manifest your activity does not recreate on orientation changed (Landscape to Portrait or vice versa). If you don't want to remove this tag from manifest you must have to override onConfigchanged and put some code logic there.

Answer (score 1):

i made it based by screen size, not dpi

```
public static int getGridColumnsCount(Context context){
    boolean landscape = context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    float hi=displayMetrics.heightPixels/displayMetrics.xdpi;
    float wi=displayMetrics.widthPixels/displayMetrics.ydpi;
    float screenWidthInch  = landscape ? Math.max(wi, hi) : Math.min(wi, hi);
    float screenWidthCm = screenWidthInch * 2.54f;
    int columns = (int)(screenWidthCm/2);
    return columns < 3 ? 3 : columns;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the XML:

```
<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="@integer/num_columns"
    android:rowCount="@integer/num_rows"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- TextViews, ImageViews, etc -->
</GridLayout>
```

And then inside your fragment:

```
@BindView(R.id.gridLayout) GridLayout gridLayout;

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    final ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < gridLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        views.add(gridLayout.getChildAt(i));
    }
    gridLayout.removeAllViews();
    gridLayout.setColumnCount(getContext().getResources().getInteger(R.integer.num_columns));
    gridLayout.setRowCount(getContext().getResources().getInteger(R.integer.num_rows));
    for (int i = 0; i < views.size(); i++) {
        views.get(i).setLayoutParams(new GridLayout.LayoutParams());
        gridLayout.addView(views.get(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this code to onCreate

```
 gridView_menu.setNumColumns(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT ? 3:4);
```